# Executing mysql on mac ignores --port argument

Tags: mysql, port

I've opened an SSH tunnel to another machine so that I can access its mysql server, but my mac appears to be ignoring the port argument when I execute `mysql`. It always shows my local server, even when I give it a bogus port number:

```
$ mysql -P 52534
mysql >
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try also adding `-h <machine-name>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a host specified that usually gets ignored. If you need to connect to `localhost`, it will always default to the local UNIX socket and not the TCP socket, so you'll need to trick it out by connecting to host `127.0.0.1`.